# How to get a user's YouTube handle after they sign in with Google?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

Is there an API to retrieve a user's YouTube handle as of today?

I cannot find anything in YouTube Data API v3 documentation.

Answer (score 0):

One more time YouTube Data API v3 doesn't provide a basic feature. As `handle` isn't found for channel handles in [YouTube Data API v3 revision history](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/revision_history), while it's a recent feature.

I recommend you to try out my [open-source](https://github.com/Benjamin-Loison/YouTube-operational-API/blob/597e1b5702a1e2aca57337388312626d2b33aa48/channels.php#L359) [YouTube operational API](https://yt.lemnoslife.com). Indeed by fetching https://yt.lemnoslife.com/channels?part=about&id=CHANNEL_ID, you will get the channel handle you are looking for in `item["about"]["handle"]`.

For instance for [`UCQxJsAlqmBPAbR_0syDi9mg`](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCQxJsAlqmBPAbR_0syDi9mg) you would get:

```json
{
    "kind": "youtube#channelListResponse",
    "etag": "NotImplemented",
    "items": [
        {
            "kind": "youtube#channel",
            "etag": "NotImplemented",
            "id": "UCQxJsAlqmBPAbR_0syDi9mg",
            "about": {
                ...
                "handle": "@Fairphone"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```